# For snap store proxy, what classifies as a "device?"

Tags: snap, snap-store

We have some 1,000+ devices distributed geographically—some in very remote places that have very limited connectivity.

We'd like to create snap store proxies in multiple regions in GCP.

For example, 2 load-balanced in US East, 2 in US West, 2 in South America, and 2 in Australia. All of these would leverage the same (replicated) Google Cloud SQL server.

This is for a few reasons:

1. Closer PoP's to reduce latency
2. Faster servers (due to lower taxation)
3. Increased redundancy (it's apparent that snap store goes down (including as I'm writing this)).

On the [registration page](https://docs.ubuntu.com/snap-store-proxy/en/register), it says:

> For evaluation purposes, we automatically grant the use of up to 25 devices.

What does this mean exactly? Does this mean that I can only have 25 proxy hosts, or does it mean that I can only have 25 devices sitting behind my proxy? If it's the latter, how do I increase this number as we'll have 1,000+ devices using our proxy.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proxy server is a system or router (device) that provides a gateway between users and the internet.

For evaluation purposes, we (Ubuntu) automatically grant the use of up to 25 devices.  Ostensibly, additional proxy servers may be authorized after the evaluation period.

Each proxy server (device) can support a large number of users depending on how well it is resourced.

Comment: Great. So it sounds like (please confirm) that given the proposed architecture above (2-3 load-balanced servers in 3-4 regions...3x4 = 12) would be allowed? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that deployment plan should fall well inside the automatic registrations for evaluation limit.  I saw nothing in the policy regarding deployment of production proxies and there may be a fee for that.  Should you need more than 25 proxies at some future date I'm sure they have a policy for that.  Please note that I am just a contributor here same as you.  I do not speak for Ubuntu.